# Append HTML string to DOMDocument node

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument

I am attempting to create a new, stripped-down DOM however I cannot find a way to take a the HTML string returned from `DOMDocument::saveHTML()` and insert that into a new `DOMDocument`.

I want to take `$courseHTML` and append it to the `<body>` node.

Is that possible, or is my approach sub-optimal?

```
// grab the original DOM
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body');

// create a new DOM just for the <body> content
$mock = new DOMDocument();
foreach ($body->item(0)->childNodes as $child) {
   $mock->appendChild($mock->importNode($child, true));
}

$courseHTML = $mock->saveHTML();

// create a new, stripped-down DOM
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$html = $doc->appendChild($doc->createElement('html'));
$head = $html->appendChild($doc->createElement('head'));

$node = $head->appendChild($doc->createElement('meta'));
$node->setAttribute('charset', 'utf-8');

$node = $head->appendChild($doc->createElement('meta'));
$node->setAttribute('name', 'viewport');
$node->setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');

$style = $head->appendChild($doc->createElement('style'));
$style->setAttribute('type', 'text/css');

$rangersCSS = $doc->createTextNode('@import url("https://crmpicco.co.uk/grfc1872.css");');
$style->appendChild($rangersCSS);

$body = $html->appendChild($doc->createElement('body'));
$body->setAttribute('id', 'crmpicco_course');

$doc->formatOutput = true;

$content = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
$content .= $doc->saveHTML();
```

*Also, is there a cleaner way to add the `DOCTYPE` to the DOM other than string concatenation?*

Answer (score 1):

Inserting an arbitrary piece of HTML string can be done by creating a `DOMDocumentFragment` from the HTML. Note this only works if the HTML is well-formed XML as well.

Creating a document with a doctype declaration can be done by constructing the `DOMDocument` object with a `DOMImplementation`.

For example:

```
<?php
$myhtml = '<p>Here is some <abbr title="hypertext markup language">HTML</abbr></p>';

$doc = (new DOMImplementation)->createDocument(
    null,
    "html",
    (new DOMImplementation)->createDocumentType("html")
);

// html element is already created
$html = $doc->getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
$head = $html->appendChild($doc->createElement('head'));

$node = $head->appendChild($doc->createElement('meta'));
$node->setAttribute('charset', 'utf-8');

$node = $head->appendChild($doc->createElement('meta'));
$node->setAttribute('name', 'viewport');
$node->setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');

$style = $head->appendChild($doc->createElement('style'));
$style->setAttribute('type', 'text/css');

$rangersCSS = $doc->createTextNode('@import url("https://crmpicco.co.uk/grfc1872.css");');
$style->appendChild($rangersCSS);

$body = $html->appendChild($doc->createElement('body'));
$body->setAttribute('id', 'crmpicco_course');

// can't just use new DOMDocumentFragment for some reason
$fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML($myhtml);
$body->appendChild($fragment);

$doc->formatOutput = true;

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style type="text/css">@import url("https://crmpicco.co.uk/grfc1872.css");</style>
</head>
<body id="crmpicco_course"><p>Here is some <abbr title="hypertext markup language">HTML</abbr></p></body>
</html>
```